Why does my manually built runnable jar respond with "Error: Could not find or load main class" when the class exists?
This is one of those error messages that comes up a lot, but none of the question/answers address this particular situation.

I am creating a runnable jar from the contents of an Eclipse project.
When I use the Eclipse IDE to create a runnable jar, it works.
When I
use java.util.zip.* functions to create the runnable jar, it does
not work.
When I compare the two files in Windows explorer they are identical.
When I extract the zip files and compare the resulting contents on disk (Using WinMerge), they are identical.

Why would one file work, and the other, seemingly identical file not work?
Here's a snip of the code that I'm using.  Not the full implementation, just the interesting bit:
    ZipInputStream zin = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(tempFile));
    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFile));
    for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileList[i]);
        String absoluteFileNameString = fileList[i].getAbsolutePath();
        if (baseDirectory != null && baseDirectory.length() > 0 && absoluteFileNameString.length() > (baseDirectory.length() + 1) ) {
            absoluteFileNameString = absoluteFileNameString.substring(baseDirectory.length() + 1);
        }
        out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(absoluteFileNameString));
        int len;
        while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
            out.write(buf, 0, len);
        }
        out.closeEntry();
        in.close();
    }
    out.close();

Here is the output showing that one works and the other doesn't:
C:\Users\Owner\git\runnablejarbuilder\RunnableJarBuilder>java -jar RunnableJarBuilder.zip
Error: Could not find or load main class com.rjb.test.HelloRun
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rjb.test.HelloRun

C:\Users\Owner\git\runnablejarbuilder\RunnableJarBuilder>java -jar RunnableJarBuilderIDE.zip
Hello Runnable Jar!

Below is a screen shot (the only way to capture what Windows explorer was telling me: the files were exactly duplicates of each other):


did you try using the corresponding classes from the java.util.jar package (JarEntry, JarOutputStream, ...) ?

@user85421 A logical thought. Not mentioned in the question, but I tried the "Jar" versions (which are subclassed from the "Zip" versions), and it made no difference in the problem at hand. IOW JarEntry doesn't alter the entry.

After analyzing the zip files using zipdump, I realized my code was using backslashes (\) as a path separator, but ZipEntry expected a forward slash (/). This was my non-working file:
C:\Users\Owner\git\runnablejarbuilder\RunnableJarBuilder\zipdump>C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe zipdump.py RunnableJarBuilder.zip
        75 ( 97.3%)  2024-11-18 12:27:10  106e3e9c [NOLFH] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      7831 ( 48.9%)  2024-11-18 12:27:10  a30be143 [NOLFH] com\rjb\test\BuildJarFromClassFiles.class
      4601 ( 53.4%)  2024-11-18 12:27:10  0742ac06 [NOLFH] com\rjb\test\ClasspathReader.class
       561 ( 62.2%)  2024-11-18 12:27:10  d38480b3 [NOLFH] com\rjb\test\HelloRun.class
      6525 ( 50.6%)  2024-11-18 12:27:10  364411d0 [NOLFH] com\rjb\test\JarUpdater.class

And this was the working one, which the IDE created:
C:\Users\Owner\git\runnablejarbuilder\RunnableJarBuilder\zipdump>C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe zipdump.py RunnableJarBuilderIDE.zip
        75 ( 97.3%)  2024-11-18 12:25:54  106e3e9c [NOLFH] META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      4601 ( 53.4%)  2024-11-18 10:44:42  0742ac06 [NOLFH] com/rjb/test/ClasspathReader.class
      7831 ( 48.9%)  2024-11-18 12:23:00  a30be143 [NOLFH] com/rjb/test/BuildJarFromClassFiles.class
       561 ( 62.2%)  2024-11-18 09:02:48  d38480b3 [NOLFH] com/rjb/test/HelloRun.class
      6525 ( 50.6%)  2024-11-18 09:46:12  364411d0 [NOLFH] com/rjb/test/JarUpdater.class

I fixed the problem by replacing all the backslashes with forward slashes in the path name:
//REPLACE THIS LINE
//String absoluteFileNameString = fileList[i].getAbsolutePath();

//WITH THIS LINE - Never use backslashes in zip file entries!!
//String absoluteFileNameString = fileList[i].getAbsolutePath().replace("\\","/");
// or better, suggested by DuncG
String absoluteFileNameString = fileList[i].getAbsolutePath().replace(File.separatorChar,"/");


This might come up on Windows especially, and may be less of a problem on Linux.

See my answer. I think .replace(File.separatorChar, '/') is better here.

Your problem is that ZipEntry uses Unix style forward slash / as path separator. However solution in your answer isn't quite correct as it could transform valid use of \ in a non-Windows path structure to a new sub-directory level inside the ZIP.
Instead of .replace("\\","/") you should .replace(File.separatorChar, '/') so that folder separators are preserved on all platforms as folder separators inside the ZIP.
Alternatively: ZIP filesystem handles Windows+other OS without String.replace, and calling Files.copy for each file and directory:
public static void zip(Path dir, Path zip) throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> env = Map.of(
            "create", "true"
            //,"compressionMethod", "DEFLATED"
            //,"encoding", "UTF-8"
    );
    System.out.println("ZIP "+dir +" to "+zip+" env="+env);
    try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(zip, env)) {
        // Find stream provides every file+folder in dir EXCEPT dir itself:
        try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.find(dir, Integer.MAX_VALUE, (p,a) -> !p.equals(dir))) {
            stream.forEach(p -> copy(p, fs.getPath(dir.relativize(p).toString())));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("ZIPPED "+dir +" to "+zip +" size="+Files.size(zip));
}
public static boolean copy(Path source, Path target) {
    System.out.println("Copy "+source+" => "+target);
    try {
        Files.copy(source, target, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
    return true;
}


Nicer looking code than mine :) More "modern".  I didn't try it, but lurkers might use this as a better alternative than what's in the original question.
